# Quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $∠BDA = ∠CDB = 50°, ∠DAC = 20°$ and $∠CAB = 80°.$ Find angles $∠BCA$ and $∠DBC.$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $∠BDA = ∠CDB = 50°, ∠DAC = 20°$ and $∠CAB = 80°.$ Find angles $∠BCA$ and $∠DBC.$

**My Attempt:**

In tri $ABD,
     ∠ABD=30°$.
In tri $ADC,
     ∠ACD=60°$.
In tri $ABC,
     ∠DBC+∠ACB=70°$.
So, if I assume $∠DBC=50°$ and $∠ACB=20°$

It is satisfying the values for all the other triangle cases.
So, can I assume this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Let's study the triangle $ACD$. Observe that $\angle \, ACD = 60$. Furthermore,   $\angle \, BAD = 80 + 20 = 100$ so if you produce $DA$ past $A$, the exterior angle at $A$ is $80$, which means that $AB$ is the angle bisector of the exterior angle at vertex $A$ of triangle $ACD$. However, by assumption, $DB$ is the interior angle bisector of vertex $D$ of triangle $ACD$. The two angle bisectors $AB$ and $DB$ meet at point $B$, which means that $DB$ is the external angle bisector of triangle $ACD$ at vertex $C$. Therefore, $$\angle \, BCA = \frac{1}{2} \big( 180-\angle \,ACD \big) = \frac{1}{2} \big( 180-60 \big) = 60$$ The other angle can be found by simple angle chasing.